# How to randomize colors except black?

Tags: java, random, colors

This line 
`g.setColor(new Color(numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256)));`
generates a random color but I don't want to include black in it for some reason. Can I restrict values for example, just 80-256 to exclude the dark colors. I tried `Math.random` and do modulo but it doesn't work. Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: i realise you wrote 80-255 to exclude dark colors, but obviously this will also exclude colors i wouldnt consider dark 255,0,0 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the to offset the number randomize in a smaller range and add the offset.

```
private int randomBetween(int min, int max) {
    int range = max - min;
    return min + numGen.nextInt(range);
}

...

g.setColor(new Color(randomBetween(80,256), randomBetween(80,256), randomBetween(80,256)));
```

This assumes you want a minimum intensity for each color component.

Comment: Note that values for color ints can only go to 255.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think I accounted for not going over 255. The way it is implemented the max is non inclusive, but maybe I was not clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
g.setColor(
  new Color(127 + numGen.nextInt(128), 
  new Color(127 + numGen.nextInt(128), 
  new Color(127 + numGen.nextInt(128));
```

Answer (score 1):

to generate numbers between 80-256:

css..

```
table {
    font: 11px/24px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 320px;
    }

td {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    }
```

html....

```
<head>        
</head>
<body>
    <div id='mydiv'></div>
    <button id = "myRandomizeBtn">Randomize</button> 
</body>
```

javascript...

```
$("#myRandomizeBtn").bind("click",randomizeHandler); 

function randomizeHandler(evt){     
var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
var tab=document.createElement('table');
tab.className="mytable";
var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
var row, cell;
var n = 3;  
var data;    

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    row=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<n;j++){
        cell=document.createElement('td');
        data = Math.floor(80+(176*Math.random())); 
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tbo.appendChild(row);
}
tab.appendChild(tbo);
root.appendChild(tab);
   }
```

here's a link to jsfiddle... hope it helps...
http://jsfiddle.net/FhyHK/